# Action event for a combobox inserted into a JTable Cell in java swing

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, netbeans-platform

I am adding a combobox to the 3rd column of a table so..every time a new row is added it will create a new combobox and adds items from those in vector1

```
TableColumn ProfileCol = Table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
ProfileCol.setCellEditor(new tableList(vector1));
```

Here tableList is a a below mentioned class that extends DefaultcellEditor and its constructor method is

```
public tableList(java.util.Vector v) {
    super(new JComboBox(v));
```

My problem is If I write an action even like

```
Table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override    
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = Table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int col = Table.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && col ==3) {

        }
    }
});
```

it is not getting triggered..

1. I need a code that will fire for every selection of item in the combo box
2. I need a code that will allow me to dynamically update the contents of the combobox that is inserted in the table

Please help with this.

Comment: why ....., is there some issue, where is the problem, you don't need a code t..., you don't need MouseListener for that, for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE / MCTRE, short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded valuse for JTable / XxxTableModel in local variable, before anything here to read official Oracle tutorial - HOw to use Tables, part ComboBox as Editor, for working code example, hint override setValueAt() in model

Comment: you have to edit your question for potential answer(s) to `1)I need a code that will fire for every selection of item in the combo box ???` --> what, where, how, this event ended inside JTable or `2)I need a code that will allow me to dynamically update the contents of the combobox that is inserted in the table` --> do you meaning editable JComboBox or

Comment: the listener code I wrote is able to trigger if I click on any cell other than column three, in which I have inserted combobox..
My actual purpose is..If I select any Item present in the combobox (that is inserted in one column of a table) I have to fetch some other data related to it from the database.. so...I need to goto a function which wll be triggered If I select an item in the combobox..I hope you got it now

Comment: the listener code I wrote is able to trigger if I click on any cell other than column three == ListSelectionListener

Comment: `Table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override    
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = Table.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int col = Table.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && col >=0) {

        }
    }
});`

Comment: Here I changed the index as col>=0..now If I select any cell other than column 3 it will trigger..

Comment: `which wll be triggered If I select an item in the combobox` == 1. override setValueAt for final status (popup from JComboBox is hide, Editor is stopped) 2. add ListSelectionListener to JComboBox if you want to firing events at runtime (selection in JComboBox as Editor)

Comment: I can do as yo mentioned only if there is one row and one combobox.every time I add a new row to the table a new combobox is generated..so how can I write an action listern to them.. 
I am not getting Idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> every time I add a new row to the table a new combobox is generated..so how can I write an action listern to them

You should NOT be using an ActionListener.

You have three options:

1. Override the `setValue(...)` method of the TableModel to do your processing
2. Add a TableModelListener to the TableModel. Then you do you processing when the TableModelEvent is generated.
3. Use a [Table Cell Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/) on your table to handle the processing.